# Wordpress 404 handler with PuPHPet Vagrant

Tags: wordpress, apache, vagrant

I am struggling to make this work - my current 404 page is served from Apache, so I can't reach my theme's 404 page nor use a plugin like media-placeholder as the 404 will have to be server by Wordpress' 404 handler instead. I've generated my Vagrant machine using PuPHPet and there's no option that covers this issue.

Comment: Could please elaborate a little more the question? What exactly if the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found out how to make it work: under config.yaml > apache > files_match I've added fallbackresource: 404.php. Provisioned the machine again after that and regenerated my htaccess file by saving the permalinks again. Lookin good so far!